# Python 3.4 ImportError: No module named '_gdal_array'No module named '_gdal_array'

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, gdal

Despite learning python (2.7) several years ago, I am just starting to use it again. 
I am using python 3.4.4 and attempting to use the GDAL package to read a raster as an array. 
I followed the steps outlined here:
 https://sandbox.idre.ucla.edu/sandbox/tutorials/installing-gdal-for-windows 
except for Python 3.4 and used the GDAL binaries from here: http://www.gisinternals.com/release.php

While testing basic functionality, I attempted to read a tiff file as shown

```
import gdal as gdal
import numpy as np
import ogr
import osr
import os
import sys
e=('error has occurred')

# this allows GDAL to throw Python Exceptions
gdal.UseExceptions()

# open dataset
test = ('LE70130312004049EDC01_sr_adjacent_cloud_qa.tif')
print("file exists")


# getting metadata
gtif = gdal.Open(test)
print (gtif.GetMetadata())
print("metadata printed")

try:
    src_ds = gdal.Open(test)
    print("gdal.open success")
except (RuntimeError):
    print ('Unable to open INPUT.tif')
    print(e)

try:
    srcband = src_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
    print("get raster band 1 success")
except (RuntimeError):
    # for example, try GetRasterBand(10)
    print ('Band ( %i ) not found') % band_num
    print (e)


try:
    rasArray=np.array(src_ds.ReadAsArray())
    print("read as array")
except (RuntimeError):
    print (e)
```

And when I run the last block with "rasArray=np.array(src_ds.ReadAsArray())" I get the following error code returned to me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal_array.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_gdal_array', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "C:\Python34\lib\imp.py", line 297, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_gdal_array'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dem12002\Desktop\test.py", line 38, in <module>
    rasArray=np.array(src_ds.ReadAsArray())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py", line 1829, in ReadAsArray
    from . import gdalnumeric
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdalnumeric.py", line 1, in <module>
    from osgeo.gdal_array import *
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal_array.py", line 26, in <module>
    _gdal_array = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal_array.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    import _gdal_array
ImportError: No module named '_gdal_array'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dem12002\Desktop\test.py", line 40, in <module>
    except (RuntimeError,e):
NameError: name 'e' is not defined
```

Is this issue with how I installed GDAL or Python? 
Should I switch to Python 2.7? 
I've seen many questions about "no module named", however not many involving GDAL issue like so.

Update:
I simply went to reinstall GDAL from the msi I had downloaded and it automatically repaired it for me. Who would've know it was that easy. Thanks!

Comment: Obviously the interface with GDAL was written with SWIG. First check that you installed a version that is compatible with your version of python. The module is looking for a dll named `_gdal_array` with a leading underscore and it can't find it. You could start with a filesystem search to find if you have this dll.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed inside the site-packages/osgeo/ I have a python file "gdal_array" but didn't know to look for the dll.

Comment: Gribouillis, I noticed I'm missing the _gdal_array.pyd from the osgeo folder, do you have any advice on how to proceed?

Comment: If you have a `_gdal_array.dll` you could try to rename it `_gdal_array.pyd`. I'm afraid I can't tell you much more than this as I don't know this module. I used Swig a long time ago, mainly in linux...

Answer (score 3):

I came accross this problem too,here is how I solved it :

```
pip3 uninstall gdal
pip3 install numpy
pip3 install gdal
```

I am using MAC OS BTW