# ImportError: cannot import name '_gdal_array' from 'osgeo'

Tags: python, gdal

I create a fresh environment, install numpy, then install GDAL. GDAL imports successfully and I can open images using `gdal.Open(`, but I get the `ImportError: cannot import name '_gdal_array' from 'osgeo'` error when trying to use `ReadAsRaster`.

`pip list` returns:

```
GDAL       3.6.2
numpy      1.24.2
pip        23.0
setuptools 65.6.3
wheel      0.38.4
```

Completely stumped, has anyone come across this? Google tells me that installing numpy first is the solution (but that doesn't help). Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: maybe related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83138/cannot-import-gdal-array & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45289299/python-3-4-importerror-no-module-named-gdal-arrayno-module-named-gdal-arra .. Both hint that if *numpy* was installed after gdal, you can get this sort of issue ..

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/274328 may help you?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but as I mentioned in my question, I have tried installing numpy before gdal as these posts suggest, and the issue persists.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pip is most likely caching and reinstalling your bad version of GDAL over and over, even though you installed numpy. Here's what fixed it for me:

`pip3 install --no-cache-dir --force-reinstall 'GDAL[numpy]==3.6.2'`

Installing without `--no-cache-dir` causes pip to reuse the compiled wheel:

```shell
% pip3 install --force-reinstall 'GDAL[numpy]==3.6.2'
Collecting GDAL[numpy]==3.6.2
  Using cached GDAL-3.6.2-cp311-cp311-macosx_13_0_x86_64.whl
Collecting numpy>1.0.0
  Using cached numpy-1.24.2-cp311-cp311-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (19.8 MB)
Installing collected packages: numpy, GDAL
  Attempting uninstall: numpy
    Found existing installation: numpy 1.24.2
    Uninstalling numpy-1.24.2:
      Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.24.2
  Attempting uninstall: GDAL
    Found existing installation: GDAL 3.6.2
    Uninstalling GDAL-3.6.2:
      Successfully uninstalled GDAL-3.6.2
Successfully installed GDAL-3.6.2 numpy-1.24.2
```

---

For others still encountering this issue, make sure `wheel` and `setuptools` are installed. Pip will think `setuptools>=48` is enough, but it's wrong, as you'll need at least setuptools 67.`

Pip will download `wheel` and/or `setuptools` as part of the building process, but it will not work (as of March 2024) and instead blame numpy:

```shell
Building wheels for collected packages: GDAL
  Running command Building wheel for GDAL (pyproject.toml)
  WARNING: numpy not available!  Array support will not be enabled
```

The only indication that it's a `wheel` or `setuptools` problem shows up when building without build isolation (`--no-build-isolation`):

```shell
  error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
```

```shell
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'
```

To fix these errors, make sure wheel and setuptools are installed with `pip3 install wheel 'setuptools>=67'`

Comment: This fixed the problem for me. I didn't know about the [syntax to install optional dependencies](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirement-specifiers/).

Comment: it worked for me after also installing wheel. Many thanks

Comment: I am having the same issue as your edit... I can not get this error to go away even running "pip3 install --no-cache-dir --force-reinstall 'GDAL[numpy]==3.6.2.'' When I run with --no-build-isolation I get the same subprocess-exited-with-error. Do you know of a solution to this issue as of March 2024?

Comment: If your subprocess error happens after the bdist_wheel statement, your install is likely missing wheel. Just to be safe, install wheel and setuptools with the following and try again `pip3 install wheel setuptools>=67`.

The new issues installing got me to finally submit a PR with updated install notes, but it looks like the change hasn't hit the doc site yet.

I hadn't realized I didn't include the wheel/setuptools install command, so I've updated my answer.