# How to install GDAL with poetry and numpy?

Tags: python, gis, gdal, python-poetry

I'm writing an application in Python 3.11, using the GDAL Python bindings to process raster data. I have `libgdal-dev` successfully installed on my system. I'm using GDAL version 3.6.2.
When I try to read a raster Band as an array, I get the following error:

```
f: Band = gdal.Open("/some/file/path.tif").GetRasterBand(1)
arr = f.ReadAsArray()
...
ImportError: cannot import name '_gdal_array' from 'osgeo'
```

I understand that this usually occurs because `numpy` needs to be installed as well. However, `numpy` is already in my pyproject.toml.
I've tried changing the order of installation; that is, I've done `poetry add numpy` before gdal, and vice versa, to no effect. I've tried installing both with `--no-cache`.
I wonder if there is something about Poetry that I'm not understanding?
Here's the dependencies section of my pyproject.toml:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.9,<4.0"
prometheus-client = "^0.14.1"
gunicorn = "^20.0.4"
uvicorn = {extras = ["standard"], version = "^0.18.3"}
pydantic = "^2.0.3"
pydantic-settings = "^2.0.2"
ddtrace = "^1.16.1"
matplotlib = "^3.7.2"
numpy = "^1.25.1"
gdal = "3.6.2"
```

To reiterate, the problem is installing GDAL+numpy with Poetry. I know there are ways to do this easily with pip, but that is not an option for me. Thank you!

Comment: I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75372275/importerror-cannot-import-name-gdal-array-from-osgeo

Comment: Thanks @XiaominWu, but my problem is getting this installation to work using Poetry, not pip. The solution given does not work with Poetry, unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

I found this [ImportError: cannot import name '_gdal_array' from 'osgeo'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75372275/importerror-cannot-import-name-gdal-array-from-osgeo)

you can install GDAL like this.

```
pip3 install --no-cache-dir --force-reinstall 'GDAL[numpy]==3.6.2'
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I tried to explain, my problem is installing this with Poetry, not with pip. The syntax of 'GDAL[numpy]==3.6.2' does not work in Poetry.